# Посредник при отправке ajax

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование, прокси

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: используем API одного сервиса, попали в черный список из-за частых обращений к нему(или что-то смежное - ответ так и не получили).

Заблокировали IP-адрес.

Существует ли сервис, которому можно передать адрес(url) и запрос, он передал бы запрос на указанный адрес, получил бы ответ и уже ответ вернул мне?
Эдакий посредник.

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Вас забанили по API ключу? Или по адресу?

Comment: @LbISS заблокировали ip

Answer (score 1):

А просто изменить ip у машины не вариант? Это было бы самое простое решение. 
В любом случае, если некий посредник (ваш или сторонний) начнёт слать аналогичные запросы, то и его так же могут добавить в чёрный список.

В первую очередь нужно узнать исходную причину блокировки и попытаться её устранить. После этого поменять ip или договориться о разблокировке. Через некоего посредника, во-первых, запросы будут идти дольше, а во-вторых, будете отдавать кому-нибудь данные, которые будут проходить через них. К том же нужно ещё найти этого самого "посредника" или поднять самим на другой машине.

Comment: посредник - это временное решение.

Comment: Про подобные сервисы не знаю. Смысл в них? На это денег не заработать, т.к. никто не будет в здравом уме добровольно отдавать кому-то трафик с персональными данными пользователей. 

Быстрее было бы поднять на другой машине "слушалку" входящих запросов, которая будет делать запросы на нужный вам сервис, и возвращать результат. О безопасности, при таком подходе, говорить не приходится. Её просто нет. Как и при посредниках.

Или использовать VPN, к примеру

Answer (score 0):

А что если отправить с динамического адреса? 
Если такое не прокатит, напишите тестовый сервер который будет эмулировать ответ вот и все.

По идее любой публичный API, он предусматривает вот такие запросы, поэтому предоставляет тестовый шлюз, либо вообще не блокирует. Вы не такой один, поверьте )